# Intro to C for an experienced programmer

Tags: learning, c

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14744/i-dont-know-c-and-why-should-i-learn-it/14747#14747) reply to the question "I don't know C. And why should I learn it?" has me interested in learning C. What is a good self-instruction program (textbook/website/OpenCourseWare, etc.) for someone who already has lots of experience in high-level languages?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a clichéd answer, but my intro to C programming was Kernighan and Richie's *The C Programming Language*.

Comment: No question this is the best resource to start with.

Comment: this is without question the best resource out there. thin, small, to the point. if you're experienced you'll know C in a few hours and instantly understand where all that stuff in the language you're using now came from. very informative.

Comment: The only drawback to using K&R2 is that it doesn't cover the C99 standard.  Since C99 support is still somewhat spotty (glares at Microsoft), this may or may not be an issue.  My day-to-day reference is Harbison & Steele's "C: A Reference Manual"; it's not a great *teaching* reference, but it will make an indispensable companion reference.

Comment: Just to echo what the others have said, this book is essential reading, for anyone, far more so for learning C.

Comment: Buy: http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628

Answer (score 1):

If your goal truly is to understand what goes on under the hood, then perhaps, instead of learning C and writing a toy program in it, you instead look at a C **compiler** and understand how that works.  As far as compilers go, a C compiler is one of the simplest, as the language doesn't have all that many high-level features.

As for which compiler, I would take a simple compiler with an easy to understand machine architecture, so you're not mucking about too much with x86 instructions.

I'd suggest the [C-- compiler](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~lenz/compiler.html) (written in Java) which outputs [MIPS](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~ellard/Courses/cs50-asm.pdf) assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Leendert Ammeraal's "C For Programmers", while VERY dated now (15 years old or more) is by far the best thing I have ever seen along these lines.